# Paperclip on a class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I would like to use papaerclip in Rails 3 on a model which is not inherited from ActiveRecord::Base. I do not need the model to be stored as the other models are, only some ActiveModel mixings will be used.

I made something like this:

```
class ThemeSettings
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validate :no_attachement_errors
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    :styles => { :mini => '48x48>', :small => '100x100>', :normal => '240x240>', :large => '600x600>' },
                    :default_style => :normal,
                    :url => "/assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  def logo_file_name
    ..
  end
  def logo_file_name=(file_name)
    ..
  end
  def logo_content_type ..
  def logo_content_type=(content_type) ..
  def logo_file_size ..
  def logo_file_size=(file_size) ..
  def logo_updated_at ..
  def logo_updated_at=(updated_at) ..
end
```

Paperclip does not like that: the `has_attached_file` method is not mixed in: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'has_attached_file' for ThemeSettings:Class`. How can I convince Paperclip to like simple classes? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Much simpler to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` even when there is no db table behind.  That way all other gems will work flawlessly. How about this -

```
class ThemeSettings < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns
    @columns ||= [];
  end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default,
      sql_type.to_s, null)
  end

  # Override the save method to prevent exceptions.
  def save(validate = true)
    validate ? valid? : true
  end

  column :logo_file_name
  column :logo_content_type
  column :logo_file_size
  column :logo_updated_at
  # You can override the = methods here.

  validate :no_attachement_errors
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    :styles => { :mini => '48x48>', :small => '100x100>', :normal => '240x240>', :large => '600x600>' },
                    :default_style => :normal,
                    :url => "/assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but theoretically this should work:

```
require 'paperclip'

class ThemeSettings
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include Paperclip

  has_attached_file # ...

  # ...
 end
```

require Paperclip and then include the Module to your class.